# How to design the Google Gmail app : ContactView screen layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, gmail, material-design, android-cardview

[image]  I am trying to create view by using below code but fails*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.soup.navigationfragmen.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have tried to make AppBarLayout visibility transparent but it didn't worked.

Comment: Can anyone please support me to implement it .

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    enter code here
    <RelativeLayout`enter code here`
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_cover_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/navigation_header_image" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/user_profile_photo"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_cover_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_circular_border_imageview"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_cover_image"
            android:background="#ebca0707"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/add_friend"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/drop_down_option_menu"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_user_add" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/drop_down_option_menu"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_profile_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
                android:text="Viral Android"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_profile_short_bio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/user_profile_name"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="Android free tutorials and example"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profile_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Android Profile UI Design" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Android Profile XMl UI Design" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Android Profile UI Design" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Android Profile XMl UI Design" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:text="Android Profile UI Design" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>



from http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/03/android-material-design-profile-screen-xml-ui-design.html
```

Comment: thanks for the help.. but I want to make it using Design library.

Comment: so that I can add various other property like scrolling